# Как сериализовать c# с одним xmlns без xsi xsd?

Tags: c#

Нужен файл, вида

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types 
 xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
 <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
```

NET вставляет свои `xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.ord/2001/XLMSchema-instance` и `xmlns:xsd`

Пишу

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class xlsx
{

    const string ns1 = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org.spreadsheetml/2006/main";

       static XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces(
                new XmlQualifiedName[] { 
       new XmlQualifiedName("","http://schemas.openxmlformats.org.spreadsheetml/2006/main"), 
     new XmlQualifiedName("r","http://schemas.openxmlformats.org.spreadsheetml/2006/main2") 
                  });



    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Types", Namespace="ns3")]

    //[XmlSchemaProvider("Qualited")]

    public class Types : IXmlSerializable  {

        public XmlQualifiedName Qualited() {
            return new XmlQualifiedName("", "");
          }


        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public static XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces { get { return xlsx._ns; } }


        [Serializable]
        public struct Override {
            public string PartName;
            public string ContentType;
           }

        [Serializable]
        public struct Default
        {
            public string Extension;
            public string ContentType;
        }




        [XmlElement(Type= typeof(Default), ElementName = "Default")]
        public List<object> data = new List<object>();


        public void Add(object o) {
            if (o is string) {
                Default d = new Default();
                d.ContentType=((d.Extension = o + "")== "xml") ? "application/xml" : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml";
                data.Add(d);
              }
          }
       }

    public static void Main() {
        Types t = new Types();
        t.Add("xml");
        t.Add("rels");

       XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Types));
      ser.Serialize(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), t);
 //        ser.Serialize(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), t,_ns);
```

}

Всёравно с# делает свои стандартные xsi xsd. Если делаю как [советуют](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/omitting-all-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-when-serializing-an-object-in-net) через namespace `Serialize(stm,obj,ns)` то на выходе у меня вид `<q1:Types` и т д, что не подходит. Как убрать xsi xsd?

Реплейсить - нет.

Через IXmlSerializable - [пробовал](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325097/remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-from-wcf), так там метод ReadXml пустой - и получается почти то что надо, без внутренностей... тоже не вариант...

Comment: `xsi` по идеи описывает стандартные типы xsd, поэтому без него, похоже, не десериализовать